# PayPal gateway has rejected request on my magento site #10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument

Tags: magento, paypal

In my magento site i am facing this error :
"PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)."
In my site if I have allowed to choose qty in decimal and if i select 1/2 yard qty then it is giving above errors, Please help about it.
And yes my total of cart is matched with order total.
please check screenshot.[image]

Comment: Well, do the totals of your cart item amounts match the order amounts?

Comment: Your cart total doesn't match the order total exactly - 6.85 divided by 2 is not 3.43. Not sure what the right thing to do is in such a situation (although I'm sure it can be found somewhere in their docs or on the 'net).

Comment: Could this be related? Not sure https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Unit-Price-and-Pack-Price/td-p/12912

Comment: Is your issue solved or not?

Comment: @Pekka웃: your url not working.

Comment: check my answer : 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98913/paypal10413-transaction-refused-because-of-an-invalid-argument